# Center elemement without centering all chidren recursively?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I wish to center all children within an element without centering all of their chilren.

```
<Col style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
  <Space>...</Space>
  <div>...</div>
</Col>
```

In this example, I am using antd. The library should not matter though. I wish to add center the Space and div element but not any of Space's or div's elements. Using textAlign will center every element contained within its scope, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox is the solution. For horizontal centering, use `justify-content`:

```css
Colu { 
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center;
    /*           or: space-evenly */
}

Colu, Space, div { 
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
}

Space, div { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px; 
}
```

```html
<Colu>
  <Space>abc</Space>
  <div>def</div>
</Colu>
```

Note I had to change `Col` in this demo, as `Col` is an existing HTML element that may only occur in a `colgroup` within a `table` element, and cannot have content.

Answer (score 0):

use display flex to center the first children:

```css
{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve via `flex`

```
{display: 'flex',alignItems: 'center',flexDirection: 'column'}
```

Example in HTML+CSS

```css
#demo{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <span style="width:100px;background:green;">
   <p>2nd child</p>
  </span>
  <button>first<button>
<div>
```